# How to delete all objects of Class in Parse Server?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I want to delete all object of my class with jobs. I have created my job and I wrote below code to achieve my goal but my code did not work.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("deleteWeeklyScore", (request) => {
    const mySchema = new Parse.Schema('WeeklyGameScore');
    mySchema.purge();
});
```

I can delete field from my schema but delete all objects does not work

Comment: I’m wondering whether you have to also do `mySchema.save();` or for an existing schema `mySchema.update();`.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Thanks @TomFox, I tried both of them but not work.

Comment: I’m not sure how else to help you myself. As there is a possible issue here I would suggest opening an issue on the JS SDK repo.

Comment: But please have a look through past issues first, and fill out the issue template as best as you can if you do open an issue.

Comment: @MisaghAghakhani where are you calling the job from? I assume the REST api call you use has the master key included? Have you looked at the logs to see if the job is actually running?

Comment: @SimpleOne I am calling the job with REST and I am sure about sending master key in header.

Answer (score 0):

`purge()` returns a promise. You have to resolve your promise.

`schema.purge().then(...)` or `await schema.purge()` or `return schema.purge()`

I don't know if Job resolves a promise.

Comment: Can you explain it more.What should I do with promise?